# Rspec 3 Rails 4 mock chained method call with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I am attempting to *mock* the following line:

```
publishers = AdminUser.where(can_publish: true).pluck(:email)
```

I have tried:

```
relation = instance_double('AdminUser::ActiveRecord_Relation')
allow(AdminUser).to receive(:where).with(can_publish: true).and_return(relation)
allow(relation).to receive(:pluck).with(:email).and_return(['email', 'email2'])
```

Unfortunately the expectation doesn't seem to match. No errors are thrown, but the methods aren't *mocked*.

I have also tried just and let pluck work.

```
  allow(AdminUser).to receive(:where).with(can_publish: true).and_return([object, object2])
```

However, this expectation is too generate and fails when it `where` matches another `where` call higher in the code.

How can I mock this line?

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use `receive_message_chain` as suggested, treat the need for such complexity as an indication that your class's interface could be cleaner.

The [RSpec docs say](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains) to *consider any use of receive_message_chain a code smell*.

A better approach would be to define a class method on `AdminUser` named something like `publisher_emails`, which which will be much simpler to stub, and also improves the readability of your code.

Comment: This is a good point and I will likely refactor the code as necessary. However, at this point, I was more curious *how* we could *mock* this line.

Answer (score 1):

You can stub method calls on doubles:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AdminUser, type: :model do
  let(:expected) { ["a@example.com"] }
  let(:relation) { double(pluck: expected) }

  it "returns the expected value" do
    allow(AdminUser).to receive(:where).with(can_publish: true).and_return(relation)
    publishers = AdminUser.where(can_publish: true).pluck(:email)
    expect(publishers).to eq expected
  end
end
```